# How to implement image button to call (no phone number input editText) in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm new new to java programming and this website. it's my 2nd program but I'm stuck with calling, sending SMS, emailing, showing location using google map. I'm using imageButtons for all of these. User doesn't need to type any numbers or addresses(not using editText to get user input) For example, it makes calls when user click on Phone icon. However, I still need a user input(the actual msg not the destination number or email address) for sending sms and email. I can do if I use editText but can't do without using editText.
How do I do this?

My wrong code:

```
public class PhoneActivity extends Activity {


    ImageButton btnphonecall;
    String phoneNumber = "091111111";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone);


        btnphonecall=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        btnphonecall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                                i.setData(Uri.parse("091111111"));
                                PhoneActivity.this.startActivity(i);  
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Could you show stacktrace?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying to my thing but sorry what is stacktrace? I'm not getting error but the program doesn't run.....

Comment: Is it compiling correctly? You should be seeing an error if there is compilation issue

Comment: I don't know if it compiled correctly but I don't see any errors.... so do you think the coding is fine???

Comment: Yes code looks good. Show me your manifest file

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
PhoneActivity.this.startActivity(i);
```

Try this

```
startActivity(i);
```

You don't have any PhoneActivity in your code.

Also add this permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I've done it but still not working.... So are you suggesting my code is sort of correct???

Comment: PhoneActivity class is on the top of the coding but however, I've tried startActivity(i); alone but still doesn't work.